# Error al importar una tabla SQL

Tags: mysql

Buenas estoy intentando crear una tabla sql que es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE `account_users` (
  `userid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `authorid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `disabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `startdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `enddate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fullname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastlogin` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `gmtoffset` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `md5hash` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `newpassword` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `nickchange` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `md5hash_2` (`md5hash`),
  KEY `startdate` (`startdate`),
  KEY `enddate` (`enddate`),
  KEY `created` (`created`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=758614 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Pero me da este error : ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'created'

y no entiendo el porque algun alma caritativa que me ayude

es un archivo que quiero importar pero necesito crear la tabla primero

Comment: Hola! El error se da porque le estás asignando un valor de 0000-00-00 00:00:00 a la columna created. Esto dejó de ser válido en versiones anteriores de mysql.

Comment: y como lo soluciono lo quito???  y ya.

Comment: [Lee sobre la restricción `NO_ZERO_DATE` en el MR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date). Y, me pregunto, ¿qué sentido tiene declarar por defecto una marca del tiempo establecida a cero? Lo propio sería declararlo así: **`timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`**, pues la utilidad de ese tipo de columnas es que asuma la marca del tiempo del momento en que se creó o se actualizó el registro. [Lee aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html), para más detalles al respecto.

Comment: es un archivo .sql que quiero importar pero necesito crear la tabla primero

Comment: Modifica el archivo, cambiando todos los `timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` por `timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Revisa los enlaces de mi anterior comentario, puede que necesites también indicar qué quieres que ocurra si una fila se actualiza, por ejemplo si quieres también un `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Y, no abras otras preguntas con lo mismo.